# Removed braces in CHECK Constraints definition after saving table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, constraints

I have a following table:

FirstTable

```
Id int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
Column1 int NOT NULL ,
Column2 int NOT NULL ,
Column3 int NOT NULL
```

After the table was created, I create CHECK constraint with following definitions:

((Column1 > 0 AND Column2 > 0) OR Column3 > 0).

After I save the table, and go to "**Manage Check Constraint**" I see that my constraint has little different definition. It's look like this:

([Column1]>(0) AND [Column2]>(0) OR [Column3]>(0)).

As we see, there is no braces I had created in definition, and SQL form other pair of braces around entire expression.

Why SQL do that? Is there any reason for doing that?

I asked this because I'm afraid that may be situations where braces located in different way then in my definition, which may lead to totally different expression.

Answer (score 1):

The precedence of AND is higher than OR so in this  case braces are superfluous.
But I think you could try it like this:

```
(Column1 > 0 AND Column2 > 0) OR (Column3 > 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly how check constraints are stored, but it's not as a textual representation. It's some more efficient data structure that allows the checks to be perfomed very quickly. As such, when you ask SQL Server to give it back to you, it doesn't know what bracketing you originally used - it just returns an expression that is the *equivalent* of what you originally specified.

What you receive is *exactly* equivalent to what your originally gave the server, in terms of the actual logic that will be applied.

> I asked this because I'm afraid that may be situations where braces located in different way then in my definition, which may lead to totally different expression.

It won't be. It will be (logically) the same expression, but you may need to perform some rearrangement yourself if you want to see this logical equivalence.

And, of course, you're perfectly free to store your original expressions in a suitable repository (such as a source control system) and just always work from them, rather than relying on what SQL Server can generate.